# Can't load css stylesheet in Codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have main CSS stylesheet for CI views, when but when load another link and switch to another page, Codeigniter have problem to locate css style-sheet?

CSS is classically linked in header, did not used frameworks helpers like `base_url();`

Comment: maybe the source is changing? Is the another pages in different folder than main?

Comment: Source is good, standard href= "/css/stylesheet.css"> All pages in views folder

Comment: Is this help? : href= "../css/stylesheet.css">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loading CSS will be

```
href= "<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/stylesheet.css"
```

And file structure would be like this

```
application
assets
    css
        stylesheet.css
system
index.php
```

---

> **Note** Make sure Base Url is set correctly.

Comment: @gogogo happy to help :)