# How to give base url in link tag codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

my CSS file is in `codeigniter/assets/abc.css`
I want to put this in `view/login.php`

so I gave like this

```
<link href="<php echo base_url('/assets/bootstrap.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

am not getting output.Tell me the solution

Comment: Try to verify the path with printing it out in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
<link href="<php echo base_url('assets/abc.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

and in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
```

[Reffer this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942840/cant-load-css-stylesheet-in-codeigniter/38943053#38943053)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the all answers, you may need to add the following code in order to use the **base_url** function

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

File Name : **application/config/autoload.php** 
NOTE : Please check whether the **$autoload['helper']** is already added or not, if added please add the **'url'** element to it

[Read doc :](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url)